# How to set up tabindex to a button inside of list item?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I am creating a custom Typeahead component and trying to make sure that the Typeahead's popup is accessible through keyboard navigation. This it my HTML markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" ...> 
    <div class="data-wrapper" tabindex="-1">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <button tabindex="0">John Doe</button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button tabindex="0">Mary Poppins</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not able to tab into buttons (when I click TAB, I go back to the address bar when only this markup is present). However, if I add `tabindex` property to `<li>` elements, I am able to tab into the list items. However, I am not able to click the buttons because keyboard is focused on the list item. How am I supposed to set up focus for the buttons to be navigable using keyboard?

EDIT: Or better yet, is it possible to change the behavior of the typeahead; so that, it is navigable using arrow keys (like select boxes).

Comment: Good examples here: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/combobox/aria1.1pattern/listbox-combo.html

Comment: Thank you for this. Using this, I was able to implement what I needed. There are some interesting caveats in here such as even if the list is empty, the list should exist in DOM for accessibility tools to work. If you add the list dynamically, it doesn't.